# Python cannot open file on imported package

Tags: python, file-io, import

I have the following folder structure.

```
application/app/src/app.py
application/app/data/test.py
```

App imports test, and it works successfully, however in test.py i want to open a file called "dummy.txt"

```
application/app/data/dummy.txt
```

When i run the app.py i get the following error:

```
No such file or directory: 'dummy.txt'
```

I'm assuming its because my sys.path is at the src folder, however when i tried the following:

```
TARGET_DIR_NAME = 'data'
sys.path.append('../'+TARGET_DIR_NAME)
print(sys.path[0])
print(dirname(sys.path[0]))
sys.path[0] = dirname(sys.path[0])+'/'+TARGET_DIR_NAME
```

it changes it right to the data folder, but it still wont open. Any help is appreciated!

I'm using python 3.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be defining some `utility` module which gives you the path based on your basepath as follows:

`PathUtil.py` can be one module in your `src` folder. And, you will calculate your paths from there.

```
import os

base_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def get_data_path(self):
    data_dir = os.path.join(base_path, "data" + os.sep)
    return data_dir
```

Now, in your file, you can import as follows:

```
 import os
 from PathUtil import get_data_path

 dummy_file_path = os.path.join(get_data_path(), 'dummy.txt')
```

Comment: And how do i use this?
For example in test.py currently in:

    from sklearn.externals import joblib
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    
    clf = joblib.load('dummy.txt')

Comment: I have updated above, You can import your utility file anywhere and get the text file.